# How to know whether a package is available for Ubuntu touch?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch

In order to verify a certain package exists for Ubuntu desktop, we know that we can explore:

> [http://packages.ubuntu.com/](http://packages.ubuntu.com)package-name

How do I know if a package exists for Ubuntu touch?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the currently supported Ubuntu Touch devices are (so far) ARM based systems I'd use the following page to perform such query:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/armhf

Comment: Thanks for the closest answer. The web site times out for me. However I found the package I'm interested in for armhf architecture. Are you sure the packages in the above repo can be installed in Ubuntu touch using apt?

Comment: You'll need to run `phablet-config writable-image` (N.B. run this on your laptop, not from adb shell), that command will make it rw and let you run `apt-get`.